# Is it possible to get analytical solution to this system of first order non-linear ODE in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, expression

I would greatly appreciate help solving this system in Mathematica.

\begin{aligned}\frac{d\theta_{1}}{dt}&=\frac{G(r_s^{2}-1)}{4(r_s^{2}+1)}\sin2\theta_{1}\sin2\phi_{1},\\\\\frac{d\phi_{1}}{dt}&=\frac{G}{{r_s^{2}+1}}\left(r_{s^{2}}\cos^{2}\phi_{1}+\sin^{2}\phi_{1}\right),\end{aligned}

The answer:

\begin{aligned}\tan\theta_{1}&=\frac{Cr_{s}}{({r_{s}}^{2}\cos^{2}\phi_{1}+\sin^{2}\phi_{1})^{\frac{1}{2}}},\\\tan\phi_{1}&=r_{s}\tan\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T}+\kappa\right),\end{aligned}
Where T:

\begin{aligned}T=\frac{2\pi}{G}\left(r_{s}+r_{s}^{-1}\right)\end{aligned}

Here $G, r_s$ are constants and $C, k$ are integration constants.

```
Clear[theta, phi, t, G, rS]

eq1 = D[theta[t],t] == (G (rS^2 - 1))/(4 (rS^2 + 1)) Sin[2 theta[t]] Sin[2 phi[t]];
eq2 = D[phi[t], t] ==  G/(rS^2 + 1) (rS^2 Cos[phi[t]]^2 +Sin[phi[t]]^2);

solutions = DSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {theta[t], phi[t]}, t];

thetaSol = theta[t] /. solutions[[1]];
phiSol = phi[t] /. solutions[[1]];

simplifiedThetaSol = Simplify[thetaSol]
simplifiedPhiSol = Simplify[phiSol]
```

I attached this simple code I wrote. The equation I am looking is initial condition dependent (Later I want to do some statistical analysis on this dependency, therefore I need analytical expression.). I wanted to see if MMA can handle this type of equations to reduce work. It gave good result for $\phi$ as it is straightforward to integrate. But once you plug it back to $\theta$ and perform integration it fails. I also tried other symbolic solvers without results.

Comment: What did you try so far, please show some code

Comment: I added some additional Information if it helps.

Comment: Where the   "answers" come from?

Comment: it works in V 13.3. The second solution is implicit. May be with assumption it can be fully solved as explicit. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os3GO.png)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the answer that I use comes from [link](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8522(64)90068-6).

Comment: @Nasser So far, I couldn't think of any.

Comment: @Nasser Solve[(G (rS^2 - 1))/(4 (rS^2 + 1)) Sin[2 theta] Sin[2 phi] == 0 && 
  G/(rS^2 + 1) (rS^2 Cos[phi]^2 + Sin[phi]^2) == 0, {theta, phi}] Does it help us?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Solve[(G (rS^2 - 1))/(4 (rS^2 + 1)) Sin[2 theta] Sin[2 phi] == 0 && 
  G/(rS^2 + 1) (rS^2 Cos[phi]^2 + Sin[phi]^2) == 0, {theta, phi}] Gives us equilibrium points. Does it help us?

Comment: @Diffeomorphismus Rather not, because solutions (see my answer) ocscilate around these equilibria

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Unfortunately, in my version 13.2 I making it two steps don't give solution but .Solve[expression == c2]

Comment: @Diffeomorphismus That is strange, my version is v12.2. Could you evaluate the first step `solphi = DSolve[ eq2 , phi[t] , t]`? Did you try my code with a fresh kernel?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks a lot for help. I think I will try to change coordinates to cartesian and see if things are better there.

Comment: @Diffeomorphismus Again my two questions: Could you evaluate the first step `solphi = DSolve[ eq2 , phi[t] , t]` ? Did you try my code with a fresh kernel?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yeap, it gave me .Solve[expression == c2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**modified**

You might solve it explicit in two steps as follows:

First we solve `eq2`which only dependes on `phi[t]`

```
solphi = DSolve[ eq2 , phi[t] , t]
(*{{phi[t] -> ArcTan[rS Tan[2 rS ((G t)/(2 (1 + rS^2)) + C[1])]]}}*)
Tan[phi[t]] -> ( Tan[phi[t]] /. solphi)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

`eq1` is solvable if we transform `TrigExpand[eq1]` first

```
soltheta=DSolve[TrigExpand[eq1] /. solphi[[1]], theta, t];
Tan[theta[t]] -> (Tan[theta[t]] /. soltheta)
```

[image]

Hope it helps!